# not authanticat user in symfony2

Tags: symfony

I am new in symfony2 and I am trying to learn login page in symfony2 but system gives me this error

> The security context contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.

My security.yml code is:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                    admin: { password: admin, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false 


        login:
            pattern:  ^/demo/secured/login$
            security: false

        emp:
            pattern:    ^/emp
            form_login:
                check_path: acme_radixemp_logincheck
                login_path: acme_radixemp_login
            logout:
                path:   acme_radixemp_logout
                target: demo
            #anonymous: ~
            #http_basic:
            #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

    access_control:
         - { path: ^/emp, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

And I am trying to run `/emp` from url

And my login function in controller is :

```
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    $login = new user();
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($login)
        ->add('Username','text',array('attr' => array('size' => '50',"value"=>"",'class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>"Please Enter Your Username")))
        ->add('Password', 'password',array('attr' => array('size' => '50',"value"=>"",'class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>"Enter Your Password")))
        ->add('login', 'submit',array('attr' => array('class    '=>"btn btn-success btn-lg","style"=>"margin-top:15px")))
        ->getForm()
    ;

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $url = $this->generateUrl("emp");
    $loginurl = $this->generateUrl("acme_radixemp_login",array("login"=>"fail"));

    $postData = $request->request->get('form');
    if(!empty($postData)) {

        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeRadixempBundle:user');
        $user_name = $repository->findOneBy(array('username' => $postData['Username'],'password'=>$postData['Password']));

        if($user_name=="") {
            return $this->redirect($loginurl);
        } else {
            //$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN'); 

            if(TRUE ===$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN') )
            {
                $session->set('username', $postData['Username']);
                return $this->redirect($url);
            }
        }
    }
}

    return $this->render('AcmeRadixempBundle:Default:login.html.twig',array('login'=> $form->createView()));

}
```

What did I forgot to do ?

Comment: Show us the paths for the login routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your check_path and login_path are not standard. If the actions for your settings are not implemented and the correct paths are not registered, your login functionality won't work.

I'd suggest you follow the example in the Symfony book:

[Using a Traditional Login Form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#using-a-traditional-login-form)

I followed it step-by-step and it worked immediately. For simple logins you won't be needing to create the loginAction or logoutAction at all, the Symfony will do everything for you. The only thing you need to create (and you can copy-paste it from the link I've sent you) is the login form. You can find all other more complex information in the book and the cookbook, both available freely on the Symfony website.

Hope this helps.